# How to list one file in each subdirectory of root folder?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, ms-dos

Apologies if this is trivial- but how do list just one file in each subdirectory of my root folder? Linux terminal or MS DOS syntax doesn't matter. I would guess it would be an ls or dir command with some parameter but I havent found anything in the manual for either command.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the directory names use -

> ls -R1 | grep -A 1 ":"

If you DON'T want to see the directory names use -

> ls -R1 | grep -A 1 ":" | grep -v ":"

Comment: You don't need `-1` when piping: `ls` automatically gives one-column output when output is not a TTY.

Comment: Also, `:` is a valid file name character which would create extra matches, and file names with embedded newlines won't be handled.

Answer (score 1):

Following command do:

```
for d in `find / -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d`; do find $d -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -n1 ;done
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a little script to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in `find . -type d` # Find directories recursively
do
  # cd into directory, quotes are for directory names with spaces
  cd "$dir"             

  # Print out directory name
  echo "In directory $dir:"

  # Force list output to be one entry per line, pipe through inverted grep to 
  # exclude directories, pipe through awk to get the first item. You can specify
  # the number of files you want.     
  ls -p1 | grep -v / | awk -v "num_of_files=1" 'NR<=num_of_files { print $1 }'

  # cd back to root directory
  cd "$OLDPWD"              
done
```

**Output:**

```
In directory .:
test.sh
In directory ./bar:
barfile.txt
In directory ./baz:
bazfile.txt
In directory ./baz/quux:
something.txt
In directory ./foo:
foofile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find -type d -print0 | xargs -0 ls | awk '/^\.\//||newdir{newdir=!newdir;print}'
```

- `find -type d` gets all subdirectories to  current directory.
- `-print0` and `-0` takes care of problematic file names (spaces, newlines and such).
- The cryptic `awk` command will continue if the line beginning matches `./` (which denotes directories) OR if the `newdir` variable is `true`. If it continues, `newdir` will be set to its opposite (i.e. `true` if it is `false` and vice versa) and print the line.

Some elaboration on the `awk` part: when a directory is encountered, `newdir` that by default is `false` (since it is not set) will be set to `true` and the directory will be printed. On the next line, `^\.\/` will not match, but `newdir` will now be `true` and the bracket will once again be run. Now `newdir` will be set to its opposite (`false`) and the line will be printed. Now no lines will be printed until the next directory comes up.

File names with embedded newlines will not be handled gracefully by `awk` in this example.